# How to reference index positions in an array for my Java card game

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on this House object for a Java group project (card game).

*I've put the parts that I need help within v and ^ dividers.*

I wrote some starter code to show what I would like to do.  I want the player to choose whether they want their ace card to be high or low.  I'm just not sure how to make the references/calls; for some reason, I've always been intimidated by and have struggled with arrays.

What I'm having trouble with is referencing a specific position in an array.  In this case it's referencing the position for the Ace card.

```
/**
 * Description: The House object handles the playing of one single hand.
 */

public class House
{
    private double currentBet;  // Player's current bet
    private double pot;         // Amount of the pot in play
    private Deck deck;          // The card deck to be used
    private Card firstCard;     // First card to be dealt
    private Card secondCard;    // Second card to be dealt
    private Card thirdCard;     // Third card to be dealt

    /**
      * Receives the current player.  Only receives a player that is active.
      * Will display two cards, get a bet amount from the player, and then
      * display the third card.  Pot amount and player's bankroll will be 
      * adjusted depending on whether the player wins or loses their bet.
      * @param currentPlayer
      */
    public void playHand(Person currentPlayer)
    {
        // If current player is not active, return
        if (!currentPlayer.getActiveplayer())
        {
            return;
        }

        // Deal first card and second card; make sure they are different cards
        do
        {
            firstCard = dealCard();
            secondCard = dealCard();
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            // If either card is an ACE, ask player if they want it to be high or low
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (firstCard.compareTo(index ACE of deck array) == 0 || 
                secondCard.compareTo(index ACE of deck array) == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Is your ACE high or low? Press 1 for high "
                                   + "or press 0 for low."  );
                int ace = keyboard.nextInt();

                if (ace == 1)
                {
                    index ACE of deck array equals 11
                }
                else if (ace == 0)
                {
                    index ACE of deck array equals 1
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid entry! Please enter 1 for high " 
                                        + "or 0 for low.");
                }
            }
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
        while (firstCard.compareTo(secondCard) == 0);

        // Display first card and second card
        System.out.println("First card drawn: " + firstCard);
        System.out.println("Second card drawn: " + secondCard);

        // Get the current player's bet
        // Deal and display third card
        // If there is an error, display error message
        try
        {
            currentBet = getBet(currentPlayer); 
            thirdCard = dealCard();
            System.out.println("Third card drawn: " + thirdCard);    
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }    

        // Adjust pot and player bankroll depending on results of Card 1, 2, and 3
        if (thirdCard.compareTo(thirdCard) == 0 || 
            thirdCard.compareTo(secondCard) == 0)
        {
            // If thirdCard is equal to firstCard or secondCard
            // Player loses double their bet to the pot
            currentPlayer.setBankroll(2.0 * -currentBet); // Decrease player bankroll
            pot = pot + (currentBet * 2.0);               // Update pot
            System.out.println("Ouch, you lose double your bet!");
        }
        else if (((thirdCard.compareTo(firstCard) == -1) &&  // thirdCard < firstCard
                  (thirdCard.compareTo(firstCard) == 1)) ||  // thirdCard > firstCard
                 ((thirdCard.compareTo(secondCard) == -1) && // thirdCard < secondCard
                  (thirdCard.compareTo(secondCard) == 1)))   // thirdCard > secondCard
        {
            // If thirdCard is in between firstCard and secondCard
            // Player wins bet; bet gets added to their bankroll
            currentPlayer.setBankroll(currentBet);  // Increase player bankroll
            pot = pot - currentBet;                 // Update pot
            System.out.println("Nice, you won this hand!");
        }
        else
        {
            // If thirdCard is not in between firstCard and secondCard
            // Player loses their bet to the pot
            currentPlayer.setBankroll(-currentBet);  // Decrease player bankroll
            pot = pot + currentBet;                  // Update pot
            System.out.println("Sorry, you lost this hand!");
        }  
    }
```

Here is a snippet of code for the Deck class.  This was written by another team member:

```
  public class Deck {
    private Card[] deck;
    private int currentCard; //index of next card to be dealt
    private int remainingCards;
    private BufferedImage tempCardImage;


    /**
     * Constructor to build a deck of cards
     */
    public Deck () throws IOException
    {
    String[] Faces = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
                        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen",
                        "King", "Ace"};
    String[] Suits = {"Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    deck = new Card[52];
    currentCard = 0;
```

Comment: Are you having problems with swapping elements in an array?

Comment: When I'm comparing the firstCard and secondCard to "index ACE of deck array", I'm not sure how to set that up so that it references that position.  Would it be something like deck[12] to reference the index position of the Ace card?

Comment: If ACE is always at the 12th index then yes

Comment: If you know that you set the value to "Ace" in your array, cant you just compare the first two cards to the string "Ace" and not worry about putting the index where ACE is at?

Comment: Would the fixed code be: `if (firstCard.compareTo(deck[12]) == 0 || 
                secondCard.compareTo(deck[12]) == 0)` then later on if the player presses 1 its `if (ace == 1) { deck[12].equals(11)}` and can I also write deck[Ace] instead?  Thank you.

Comment: I meant firstcard.compareTo("Ace") == 0. But that should work as well and can you explain what the other parts of your code are supposed to do so i can understand?

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know I could do that!  Cool.. so I could do firstCard.compareTo("Ace") ?

Comment: Well not quite because firstCard is of type card and "Ace" is of type string so i would stick with using the array the way you showed me. To set ACE to a different index you'll need to learn how to shift elements of an array which is prettt simple.

Comment: The second part is would it be faulty to make the `deck[12] = 11` if the player chooses for their Ace card to be high (and vice versa if they want it to be low)?  Thank you.

Comment: This question needs revision. Stackoverflow answers are supposed to be useful for others. Nobody will ever search for "help writing a poker game'. The thing you're trying to do is only relevant to you -- but other people use the things you use. People search for how to do specific programming tasks -- sort a list, using the * memory operator in C++, etc. If you can figure out specifically what part of computer science you're having trouble with, it could be a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently comparing a Card object to a String, which won't work. In your Card class you need an accessor method to access the string representing the face.

Changing the index is a very confusing way to change a value so add an int field named value, setValue() mutator method and getValue() accesor method to the Card class.

Once all that is done this is the code that goes between the arrows.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if(firstCard.getFace().equals("Ace")){
    int aceControl=0;
    while(aceControl!=1&&aceControl!=11){
        System.out.print("Type 1 if your Ace is low and 11 if it is high");
        aceControl=in.nextint();
    }
    firstCard.setValue(aceControl);
}
if(secondCard.getFace().equals("Ace")){
    int aceControl=0;
    while(aceControl!=1&&aceControl!=11){
        System.out.print("Type 1 if your Ace is low and 11 if it is high");
        aceControl=in.nextint();
    }
    secondCard.setValue(aceControl);
}
```

Feel free to ask if you have questions. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much!  It helps a lot.  It also made me see a logical error in the way that I had it set up.  You also taught me that there's a difference between using & and &&; I actually didn't know that we could use a single & because we always use && in class.

Comment: wait, i messed that up lollll I'm editing it to &&, don't use &.

Comment: Did you try adding it to the code? If so, does it work?

Comment: Ooohh okay haha, well it's still something new learned!  Yes I added it and it worked perfectly, thank you!